# Debug Haskell composition chain without converting to point-full representation

Tags: debugging, haskell, syntactic-sugar, function-composition, pointfree

I have learned that point-free style is preferred in the Haskell community, and I often write expressions like this:

```hs
naive = (slugifyUnicode . T.take maxFilenameSize . T.pack . stripHtmlTags . T.unpack . plainToHtml) sfld
```

However, while debugging, I find myself repeatedly converting expressions like this into chains of `$` operators in order to use some variant of `trace`, and I am starting to think it is preferable to forgo the point-free style and just write lots of `$`s to start with, in order to make debugging less cumbersome. After all, it ends up being about the same number of characters.

Does anyone know of a way to debug long chains of composed functions without de-composing them?

And more generally, any comments on this inconvenience are very welcome.

Comment: "I have learned that point-free style is preferred in the Haskell community" -- note that's not always the case. From what I observed, the community loves point-free style only when it leads to elegant and clear code. However, in many cases applying point-free leads to a mess, and it is jokingly referred to as "point-less style" by the community. In your case, the code is nice, but be careful. Also, `f . g . h $ x` works as expected and is quite idiomatic.

Comment: "Point-free style is preferred by the community?" What?

Comment: What would `naive` look like after you un-point-free'd it and inserted a `trace`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I would be happy to be told I'm wrong. I am not an oracle for the consensus opinion of all users, obviously.

Comment: @DanielWagner I would usually break half of it into an intermediate value defined in a `where` clause, `trace` it there, and then do the rest of the computation at the original site of the expression.

Comment: In general, the community prefers pointfree style in cases like yours where it's simple, but not in more complicated cases where you'd need operator sections or the `Applicative` or `Monad` instances for functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any intermediate value that has a `Show` instance you can just use `traceShowId` inline:

```hs
naive = (slugifyUnicode . T.take maxFilenameSize . traceShowId . T.pack . stripHtmlTags . T.unpack .plainToHtml) sfld
```

If the intermediary value is a `String` you can use `traceId` instead.

For anything that doesn't have a `Show` instance you'd have to define a helper:

```hs
data CustomType = CustomType String
traceHelper :: CustomType -> CustomType
traceHelper s@(CustomType c) = trace c $ s

-- arbitrary functions we want to compose
a :: aIn -> CustomType
b :: CustomType -> bOut

c :: aIn -> bOut
c = b . traceHelper . a
```